# Protractor browser.actions().dragandDrop async await not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor

- Node Version: 8.2.1
- Protractor Version: 5.2.2

I am converting existing tests to use async await with protractor, and I can't seem to get this code to work properly. I realized it doesn't return a promise, at least according to the protractor [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions).

The action that seems to happen is, that it clicks the area that I want to drag, then the area I want it to drag to it will select all the text.

So it's like it clicks the first element, but somehow doesn't drag it.

Has anyone had any success with dragAndDrop and async await?

I'm open to alternative workarounds.

```
    browser.actions()
    .dragAndDrop(
        elem1,
        elem2
    ).perform());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many attempts and trying different things. I have found this solution to work. I am going to implement it into a helper function moving forward.

```
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(elem1).perform();
    await browser.actions().mouseDown().perform();
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(elem2).perform();
    await browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();
```