# Protractor after disabling control flow cannot find element

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I've disabled the control flow and started spreading async/await accross my e2e tests.

And here the problem arises that

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .OneLine)
>
> NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .OneLine)

Here is my test

```
it('', async () => {
await page.dragElToCell('Text', {x: 1, y: 0});
// further some expectations that are not reached due to error thrown which points to page.dragElToCell
})
```

This is a page obj method

```
async dragElToCell(name: string, pos: {x: number, y: number}) {
  const el = this.getDraggableEl(elName);
  const cell = this.getCell(pos.x, pos.y);
  return browser.actions().dragAndDrop(el, cell).perform();
}

getDraggableEl(name: string) {
  return element(by.cssContainingText('.draggable', name);
}

getCell(x: number, y: number) {
  return $$('.OneLine').get(y).$$('.Column').get(x);
}
```

This code was working pretty well inside control flow. As soon as I've disabled it it stopped working.

The trick is that if I execute

```
  expect(await $$('.OneLine').get(0).$$('.Column').get(1).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

inside my test suite it works fine and gives me `true`.

I've also debugged `getCell` and it receives proper numbers.

Also, I've set sleep for 10 sec to ensure that elements are visible (and for that also executed `querySelectorAll` twice to repeat same sequence and got the element I'd expected to retrieve).

Comment: Eventually came up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349429/protractor-browser-actions-draganddrop-async-await-not-working as the only working solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`getDraggableEl` and `getCell` return a `Promise`. So you need to add `await` in `dragElToCell` such as:

```js
async dragElToCell(name: string, pos: {x: number, y: number}) {
  const el = await this.getDraggableEl(elName);
  const cell = await this.getCell(pos.x, pos.y);
  return browser.actions().dragAndDrop(el, cell).perform();
}
```

Comment: Since when `$` started returning Promises? It returns an `ElementFinder` what is proved by PhpStorm code assistance